# How do I post to a nested field in a complex mongoDb schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoDb schema that I want to make a post request to but I am having some problems with it.
Below is the schema in a model folder found in root directory of my app.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
UserID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
  },
  User_Info: {
    First_Name: {
      type: String,
    },
    Last_Name: {
      type: String,
    },
    Current_Address: {
      type: String,
    },
    Email_Address: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
      Phone_Numbers: [{
        Home_Phone: {
          type: Number,
        },
        Work_Phone: {
          type: Number,
        },
        Cell_Phone: {
          type: Number,
        },
            Phone_verified: [{
              Home: Boolean,
              Work: Boolean,
              Cell: Boolean,
            }],
      }],
})
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I also have an express server api as follows

```
const router = express.Router();
const ComplexPost = require('../models/ComplexPost');

    router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        try{
            const complexposts = await ComplexPost.find().sort({date:-1});
                res.json(complexposts);
        }   catch(err){
                res.json({message: err});
        }
    });

  router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    ComplexPost.create({
        UserID: req.body.userid,
        User_Info: req.body.userinfo,
        First_Name: req.body.firstname,
        Last_Name: req.body.lastname,
        Current_Address: req.body.currentaddress,
        Email_Address: req.body.emailaddress,
        Phone_Numbers: req.body.phonenumbers,
        Home_Phone: req.body.homephone,
        Work_Phone: req.body.workphone,
        Cell_Phone: req.body.cellphone,
        Phone_Verified:req.body.phoneverified,
        Home: req.body.home,
        Work: req.body.work,
        Cell: req.body.cell,
    });
    try{
    await ComplexPost.save()
    res.redirect('/');
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and in my **index.js** file I have the following code;

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Middlewares
require('dotenv/config');
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Body Parser Middleware 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

// Import routes
const complexRoute = require('./server/complexPost');
app.use('/complex', complexRoute);

// Serving static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect( 
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
    {  useNewUrlParser: true ,
       useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    },
    () => console.log('Connected to DB')
);

const port = process.env.PORT || 1100;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`));
```

When I try to make a post request using Postman as below;

```
{
    "userid": "hi",
    "userinfo[firstname]": "Albert",
    "userinfo[lastname]": "Attakora",
    "userinfo[currentaddress]": "Kumasi",
    "userinfo[emailaddress]": "Kum@gmail.com",
    "phonenumbers[homephone]": ["alb"],
    "phonenumbers[workphone]": ["031"],
    "phonenumbers[cellphone]": ["02098767865"]
}
```

I get this results without userinfo and phonenumbers details

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5eca8b45feeb163e7cc46662",
        "UserID": "hi",
        "Phone_Numbers": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Please what am I missing. Am stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're sending the data while postman in wrong format I guess

```
"userinfo[firstname]": "Albert" // here, userinfo is not defined as an object
```

also if you need to use this format, it should be a string inside the square brackets, as if you don't, then you will got an error that firstname is not defined,

for javascript you may use it like this

```
"userinfo['firstname']": "Albert", // this is a side note, for javascript only
```

or using the dot notation like this `"userinfo.firstname": "Albert"`

this is the javaScript part, regarding your request, I think you should pass the data in this format in postman

```
{
    "userid": "hi",
    "userinfo": {
        "First_Name": "Albert",
        "Last_Name": "Attakora",
        "Current_Address": "Kumasi",
        "Email_Address": "Kum@gmail.com"
    },
    "phonenumbers": [{
        "Home_Phone": "alb",
        "Work_Phone": "031",
        "Cell_Phone": "02098767865"
    }]
}
```

note that the schema has three fields only: `UserID, User_Info, Phone_Numbers`

`User_Info` is an object contains `First_Name, Last_Name, ..` , so there is no property called `First_Name` in the schema, it should be `User_Info.First_Name`

also, `Phone_Numbers` is an array of objects, each object has `Home_Phone, Work_Phone, ...`, so there is nothing in the schema called `Home_phone` or `Work_Phone`

by this JSON provided to postman, we are following the schema, so we can use the following code in the `post route`

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    ComplexPost.create({
        // just define the required three fields in the schema, UserID, User_Info, Phone_Numbers
        UserID: req.body.userid,
        User_Info: req.body.userinfo, // req.body.userinfo now has the full info (First_Name, Last_Name, ... ) with the same names as defined in the schema, so we can use the object directly
        Phone_Numbers: req.body.phonenumbers, // req.body.phonenumbers now has the full info about the phones, with the same names as defined in the schema


        // all the following do not exist in the schema

        // First_Name: req.body.firstname,
        // Last_Name: req.body.lastname,
        // Current_Address: req.body.currentaddress,
        // Email_Address: req.body.emailaddress,
        // Home_Phone: req.body.homephone,
        // Work_Phone: req.body.workphone,
        // Cell_Phone: req.body.cellphone,
        // Phone_Verified: req.body.phoneverified,
        // Home: req.body.home,
        // Work: req.body.work,
        // Cell: req.body.cell,
    });
    try {
        await ComplexPost.save()
        res.redirect('/');
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```

---

### Update

If you cannot control the field names as they are coming from a client side, so you can just send the details of each property in the schema, and then in the post route we can assign them,

I suggest you to do the following

the data passed to postman should be like that

```
{
    "userid": "hi",
    "firstname": "Albert",
    "lastname": "Attakora",
    "currentaddress": "Kumasi",
    "emailaddress": "Kum@gmail.com",
    "homephone": "alb",
    "workphone": "031",
    "cellphone": "02098767865"
}
```

and in the post route, we can do the following

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    ComplexPost.create({
        UserID: req.body.userid,

        // User_Info: req.body.userinfo, // no userinfo in the req.body now, we will create it here in the post request
        User_Info: {
            First_Name: req.body.firstname,
            Last_Name: req.body.lastname,
            Current_Address: req.body.currentaddress,
            Email_Address: req.body.emailaddress,
        },


        // Phone_Numbers: req.body.phonenumbers, // no phonenumbers in req.body
        Phone_Numbers: [{
            Home_Phone: req.body.homephone,
            Work_Phone: req.body.workphone,
            Cell_Phone: req.body.cellphone,
        }],

    });
    try {
        await ComplexPost.save()
        res.redirect('/');
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ message: err });
    }
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thank you, it worked and I do appreciateyour response but you know my goal is to be able to make the post request from an html form.  How should I name the input fields. This is what I have tried for now but it did not work;` <form action="http://localhost:1100/complex" method="post"><label for=""> userid: <input autocomplete="off" class="input" required type="text" name="userid"></input></label>
 <label for=""> firstname: <input autocomplete="off" class="input" required type="text" name="userinfo[firstname]"></input></label>
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form> `

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you check it again?, also you can change the variables names in html, you can name the first name field like "firstname" instead of "userinfo[firstname]", and so on for all the rest of fields

Comment: this "firstname", "lastname", ... properties will be send to the post request, so we can insert them to db as I did in my updated answer, hope it helps

Comment: Yes, It worked perfectly as you explained. Thank you ones again and will get intouch for any clarification that I may need. Going back to continue my project, Cheers.

Comment: glad to help you :)